# How can I make calendar view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, calendar

I want to make simple calendar app in Swift 2, but I don't know where to start. I know there are some great calendar components available in cocopoads but docs for them are unfinished and as a beginner it is hard for me to read them and investigate code. I downloaded some popular cocoapods and played with them but that one functionalty I need is missing.

I want to make simple menstrual diary for a practice with dates and other stuff. I imagined this would be simple but after a day of investigating I thing it is rather hard. Maybe I'm wrong.

So how I make my own calendar view? Should I start with tableview and collection view for dates?

Can somebody give me some pointers, I'm lost at this point. Shoud I somehow learn to make my own view (I am a beginner so maybe this is too hard) or shoud I use some custom calendar?

Comment: see -> https://github.com/satishVekariya/SVCalendar

Comment: To Add Calendar Events you should check https://github.com/RamdhanChoudhary/A-Simple-iOS-App-for-Calender-Event-written-in-Swift

Comment: This should be reported to Apple as a request. I'm happy to vote if someone opens one.

Comment: Also, this question is valid, and should not be closed. The answer should be `CollectionView.calendar`. Just need Apple to create it first... ah, details

Comment: You can use UIDatePicker from iOS 14(GraphicalDatePickerStyle)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Apple has **no** calendar control, and many developers are lost in how to build one.

A good cocoapod that is well documented is [this one](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar). It was developed by myself. If you need help setting up things, I can provide that. Full tutorials to get you started located [here](https://patchthecode.com).

If however, you want to know how it was built inside out so that you can build one yourself, then you can check out [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170506011738/http://blog.karmadust.com/lets-create-a-calendar-using-a-uicollectionview/). It shows you in detail how it was built using a UICollectionView. Since you said you are new to programming, the first option is easier in my honest opinion for now.

But you're a coder, and at some point you should learn. So I suggest learning swift/objective-c until you become comfortable with it. Start out with simple projects like creating a table view etc. Learn how delegation works etc.

Once you are better at views, delegation, etc, then you will be more comfortable to create you own calendar control.

Comment: Yea, that's me :D I forgot about this question and I've found your Calendar some time later and figured out a way on how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: How can I use this library on swift 2.2. I am not using swift 3.0.

Comment: @Dory Just use version 5.0.1 in your pod file. Version 5.0.1 was the last version that  supports swift2

Comment: Okay thanks. 
I have one more question, How can I move to current date in calendar without animation.

Comment: @Dory the fastest way to get all questions answered is by creating new issues on github on [this link](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues). But in order to move to date without animation, is using the `scollToDate` function. Can you open an issue on that github link so we can chat?

Comment: Am I allowed to use some of this source code in an app I'm making

Comment: @Jack its 100% free.

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile hii i need help in creating event in google calendar swift , i successfully run the sample code of google calendar

Comment: looks great! have you done a yearly view? trying to figure out best way. have a month view based on collection view

Comment: That link about building a calendar from UICollectionView... is dead.

Comment: check out that link in way back machine archive then

Comment: @skinsfan00atg yearview is implemented in version 8.0.1 +

Comment: Oh, come on Apple

Comment: Hi, does this cocoapod support preselecting dates?

Comment: yes it does. Try it out.